# Simple.json extract float

Tags: java

I've been trying to read values out of a JSON, but i can't extract float variables.

In this example, i try to extract the first value (23.21) but i get an error.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Double cannot be cast to class java.lang.Float (java.lang.Double and java.lang.Float are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Then when i try to extract the second value (58) i get an other error

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class java.lang.Double (java.lang.Long and java.lang.Double are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Do you have a solution ? I want to extract my values as float variables.

```java
public class testJSON {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String inputJson = "{\"AP_ID\":\"123456\",\"PI_ID\":\"12\",\"values\":[{\"type\":\"Temperature\",\"value\":23.21},{\"type\":\"Luminosity\",\"value\":58}]}";

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        try {
            JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(inputJson);

            String AP_ID = (String) json.get("AP_ID");
            String PI_ID = (String) json.get("PI_ID");
            JSONArray values = (JSONArray) json.get("values");

            values.forEach( value -> extractValue((JSONObject) value, AP_ID, PI_ID));

        }catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void extractValue(JSONObject value, String AP_ID, String PI_ID){

        String type = (String) value.get("type");
        System.out.println(type);
        System.out.println(value.get("value"));

        var readValue = (float) value.get("value");

        InputValue inputValue = new InputValue(readValue, AP_ID, type, PI_ID);

    }

}
```

Comment: Don't cast, use [Float.valueOf(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)).

Comment: What is the library or full namespace of the `JSONObject` class you are using?

Comment: You can use `getDouble()` or `getLong()` to get the value in the specific type you want.

Comment: I am using the JSON.simple library.

Comment: So I went for Float.valueOf(string) and it worked well.
Thank you @JoakimDanielson